# Run external bash script using Magento 2

Tags: magento2, external, shell

I'd like to create a file (e.g. script.sh) that will reside on the same server as my Magento 2 instance.

I'd like to be able to call a URL (e.g RunScript.php) that would in turn execute this script

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP command `shell_exec()`.

This takes a bash command as input which is executed. 
In your case it would be something like this:

```
<?php // RunScript.php
echo shell_exec('sh script.sh'); // run script and show output
?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

**Do not do this!**

This approach is highly discouraged as it has all kinds of security vulnerabilities. If the `script.sh` has an error or one too many `rm` calls it could break your server. Requiring this solution implies a severe design flaw.